# Meteor individual user timers - setInterval()

Tags: meteor

I am building an online quiz system using Meteor. Every use in the quiz is expected to have his own timer set to one hour. The timer is supposed to start when the user first logs in.
I am currently maintaining a collection called UserClocks( userId, timeLeft ).

I wrote a setInterval like this

```js
var interval = Meteor.setInterval(function() {

    console.log("User id: " + this.userId);
    console.log("Searching clock for: " + clocksMap[this.userId]); 
    //clocksMap contains the _id of the UserClocks.
    var userClock = UserClocks.find({_id: clocksMap[this.userId]});

    if (!!userClock) {
        console.log("Found clock: " + userClock.timeLeft);
    } else {
        console.log("Clock not found for user: " + this.userId);
    }

    var time = userClock.timeLeft;
    time = time - 1;
    UserClocks.update(userClock._id, {timeLeft: time});
    console.log("Updated userClock. timeleft: " + time);

    if (time === 0) {
        //logout user and clear interval
        Meteor.clearInterval(intervalMap[this.userId]);
    }

}, 1000);
```

This setInterval() is inside a method which is called b the user.
I keep getting timeLeft as NaN as userClock is undefined.
I think I understand why I can not use this.userId inside the setInterval(), but I need a solution to my problem. How can I set the timer individually for each user ?

Comment: I also tried userId from the method's parameters to the .find(). It still returns undefined for timeLeft !

Comment: What if the user enters in the console, `UserClocks.update(userClock._id, {timeLeft: 999999})`?

Comment: I tried but got undefined. However, UserClocks.find({_id: "o8y5nw4Wp5H7SF8bP") returned a LocalCollection.Cursor. I am using the insecure package and have put my UserClocks in my model.js being shared

Answer (score 1):

Put this code inside a `Meteor.methods` block. You can use `Meteor.userId()` inside the `setInterval` function, but not `this.userId`. In the callback, `this` will probably be set to `window`, which does not have a `userId`.

If you are running this inside a `Meteor.publish` callback, store the `userId` beforehand:

```
var userId = this.userId;

Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    clock = UserClocks.find({_id: userId});
    // Do stuff
}
```

The other thing I would recommend, as you see above, is to just store the docs in `UserClocks` either with `_id` or `userId` corresponding to `Meteor.userId()`. It doesn't make sense to keep a separate map outside of a collection.

Comment: I tried what you had sugged. userId works fine outside and inside the setInterval(). I was also trying it by passing it as parameter to the method. This setInterval is already inside a method which is inside Meteor.methods block. AFter trying what you had suggested I am still getting timeLeft and clockId as undefined.

Comment: Output :CLock id: 5EZgsavncGBBXr8Qj
I20140125-02:10:03.546(5.5)? User id: JFPfgyeordrME6m4M      
I20140125-02:10:03.547(5.5)? Searching clock for: 5EZgsavncGBBXr8Qj      
I20140125-02:10:03.547(5.5)? Found clockundefined      
I20140125-02:10:03.547(5.5)? Found clock: undefined      
I20140125-02:10:03.553(5.5)? Updated userClock. timeleft: NaN     
I20140125-02:10:04.551(5.5)? User id: JFPfgyeordrME6m4M